# How to add atom types in Autodock Vina

Tags: docking, autodock

The following problem arises when I use Vina for virtual screening. Vina seems to have only one calculation program, so how do I add the required atomic force field parameters?
"ATOM syntax incorrect: "Si" is not a valid AutoDock type. Note that AutoDock atom types are case-sensitive."

Comment: Similar question [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6991/24).